# Automate Facebook Signup not able to select female radio button

Tags: java

I am trying to create new account on FB but I am not able to select radio buttons and signup button

```
public void f() {  
      driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_g")).sendKeys("Anamika");
      driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_i")).sendKeys("Singh");
      driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_l")).sendKeys("9718257931");
      driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_s")).sendKeys("P@ssw0rd1");
      WebElement add=driver.findElement(By.id("day"));
      Select dropDown=new Select(add);

      dropDown.selectByIndex(6);
      add=driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
      dropDown=new Select(add);
      dropDown.selectByIndex(4);
      add=driver.findElement(By.id("year"));
      dropDown=new Select(add);
      dropDown.selectByIndex(6);

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id=u_0_j]")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id=u_0_n]")).click();
      //WebElement lstitem=driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_6"));
      //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      //if(elem.isSelected())

      //driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_10")).click();
      //else
          //System.out.println("Button not selected");
  }
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
      driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");//get to hit the URL

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      //driver.quit();
  }

}
```

Getting Following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:

Comment: _“I am trying to create new account on FB”_ - then use the UI. Creating accounts using any such automation is not allowed. Plus, you are only allowed to have one personal profile to begin with. I can’t see any actual, allowed use case that would require doing this.

Comment: I am just practicing it I have no intentions of keepimg this profile

Comment: why practice something that is not allowed at all anyway? why not use your own platform for practicing stuff like that?

Comment: OK will make sure of that in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try CSS selectors:

Female radio button:

```
input[type='radio'][value='1']
```

Male radio button:

```
input[type='radio'][value='2']
```

I already have automated this using Selenium Page Object Model, you can find this on github: https://github.com/prat3ik/Facebook_SignUp_Selenium

> **Path:** /src/test/java/

Answer (score 0):

According to FB home page

xPath for female:

```
//*[@name='sex' and @value='1']
```

xPath for male:

```
//*[@name='sex' and @value='2']
```